# Any kotlin ORM for SQL?

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, orm, ormlite

Is there any useful and easy-to-use kotlin ORM for SQL? Like ORMLite. I'm making an app for android and i need to keep data classes there.

Honestly, I'm rewriting an android [lasertag configurator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLmFd.png) from java to kotlin.

Comment: Someone said to use room but i think it's too hard for me now. I want to find a normal orm and make as less mistakes as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) persistance library.

It's part of Android Jetpack Architecture Components.

It is well designed, versatile, easy to use and stay behind an interface in your code so you do not create a strong dependency.

It is also integrated with RxJava (if you wish to use it with it) and Kotlin Coroutines. Works well with both Kotlin and Java. Have a small integration with Android Studio too, highlighting the SQL you write in your annotations.

Follow the link above, it contains links to example projects, codelabs and more.